# Create a registration form for FBA site

Tags: forms-authentication

I have an FBA based site in SharePoint 2010.

I want the users to create their accounts using the registration section. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3):

You can perform following steps to make the registration form available to anonymous users (i.e. prospected FBA users).

1. Extend the web application and enable anonymous access to the extended site.
2. Configure the FBA authentication from IIS. The steps to follow for enabling FBA are provided [here](http://blog.morg.nl/2011/08/step-by-step-forms-based-authentication-fba-on-sharepoint-2010/)
3. Create registration form web part the will accept data from users while registering themselves.
4. In `Submit_Click` you can place the code to create the user in FBA. And send e-mail of credential to the user who has registered. To create user in FBA database you can call stored procedure. This [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg252020%28v=office.14%29.aspx) provides the steps to create the FBA user.

Though I have not provided the code, but this idea may be helpful to implement the registration form for FBA users.

Comment: I have created the FBA site . All i'm missing is on the 3rd point you mentioned . Can you elaborate that and also if possible can let me know how to insert data from a webpart in SQL server database

Comment: You can create the Visual Web Part from the visual studio and deploy it to the native site (i.e.the site where you want the user to land). Create new page and add the web part to the page. You have to give the URL of that page to the users. As the site is allowed to be accessed by anonymous users, prospective users wont have to be logged in to your site and they will be able to fill the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FBA pack available for user registration,Forget Password and Change password in CodePlex.
You can find same on link: https://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/

Comment: I want to add some more fields in registration page , How should i approach to this ?